# Handling Browserify externals in Jest

Tags: reactjs, browserify, jestjs

I have a React project which uses Browserify externals. What's the best approach for testing components which reference external dependencies in Jest? For example - I have something like this...

```
import React from 'react';
import someExternal from 'someExternal';

class MyClass extends React.Component {
    methodToTest() {
        ...
        someExternal.doStuff();
        ...
    }
}
```

This works as expected in the browser, the bundle which exposes `someExternal` is available, so `someExternal`'s path can be resolved.

However in my unit test, the path to `someExternal` can't be resolved, because the bundle which contains `someExternal` is not available.

Sooo what's the best approach here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK solved. You can use manual mocks, which Jest loads before it tries to load the actual module.

https://facebook.github.io/jest/docs/manual-mocks.html